# How to get the 3D view of UI in Xcode 6?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode6

I am a newbie in this field of development.
I started using Xcode 6 after using Xcode 5.1.1 for a week.

After getting fascinated with newly added features, I installed Xcode 6.

Now, I am not able to find this 3D view of UI in ios.

I am using OSX 10.9.4.

Comment: did you ever figure this out? i'm in the same boat right now

Answer (score 53, accepted):

1. Run the app. View Debugging works in the simulator and on devices, but it's important to note that it needs to be an **iOS 8** simulator or device. That said, you may allow earlier deployment targets in your project, just make sure you run on iOS 8 when you try View Debugging.
2. Navigate to the screen/view that you want to inspect within the running app.
3. In the Navigators Panel (left column), select the Debug Navigator (sixth tab). Next to your process, you'll see two buttons – press the rightmost button and select `View UI Hierarchy`.

[image: View Debugging]

Alternatively, use the menu:

[image: View Hierarchy]

4. Xcode will stop your app and lets you inspect your views. There's no need for you to set a breakpoint, Xcode will do that for you. However, if you want to set a breakpoint manually to inspect local variables etc. alongside your views, you can set a normal breakpoint and once the app pauses, press the View Debugging button in the Debug Area (bottom panel):

[image: Debug Area]

Comment: The view debugging icon doesn't show up for me using a real device (iPhone 6 with 8.1)

Comment: Not sure what's the reason for that... I just tried it on the same configuration (iPhone 6, iOS 8.1) and it works fine here. I suspected view debugging may require the Debug configuration, but it even works with Release builds. Have you tried it with different projects?

Comment: This should be accepted as the answer. Thank you! (Note: also works for 64-bit devices such as the 5S simulator, on Xcode 6.1.)

Answer (score 9):

Xcode6.0.1 View Debugging only can be used on iOS8 and 32-bit device .I do not know if this is a bug.

Comment: Spent a lot of time scratching my head why teh option wasn't appearing no more

Comment: For iPhone Simulator testing this would be iPhone 5 (8.x) and lower (iPhone 5s is 64-bit)

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean `View Debugging`?

If so:

1. Run the app in the simulator
2. At the point you want the 3D view select (in Xcode) `Debug->View Debugging->Capture View Hierarchy`

Answer (score 1):

For view debugging in Xcode 6 add a breakpoint that you want to debug.

When the app stops you can press this button...

[image]

And Xcode will enter view debugging on the current screen.

The app needs to be paused on a breakpoint though.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need see your phone view in the debug view, if not do as @hagi told.

Second, click(hold) one component of the view and drag, then you'll find it out.

Here is a video, give it a try. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KUjbhGOV7DM
from(http://natashatherobot.com/xcode-6-debug-view-hierarchy-storyboard/)

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was working on iPhone 5S (or less) simulator, but not on iPhone 6 (all on iOS8)
But I was supporting iPhone 6 with the correct `Launch Screen.xib`

Answer (score 0):

Worth noting for this problem is that if you're running a 64bit device, your target needs to be configured so that arm64 is in both your Architectures and Valid Architectures build settings.

If you don't have that, you can debug your views on a 32 bit device, but not 64.