# iPhone 6s not receiving any touches on UIButtons

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, xcode7, iphone-6-plus

My Application works on every device except some iPhone 6s. When user tries to tap on buttons nothing happens. I checked Buttons frames and everything is right but still nothing happens when user taps on buttons. I think this is something touch related. Any kind of help here will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: can you add code related to that button?

Comment: It's happening on every button irrespective of what code I add. Still you can check code below: button pressed method -  UIStoryboard* storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    NSString *identifierStr;
identifierStr = @"BTRegistrationLandingViewController";
 BTRegistrationLandingViewController *registrationStepOneVC = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:identifierStr];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:registrationStepOneVC animated:YES];

Comment: check your outlets, actions in storyboard or xib, are they proper?

Comment: Yes that's the first thing I checked

Comment: Please check if the button is having a 3D Touch Enabled .

Comment: Most likely you have an issue with your constraints. ill defined or missing constraints can manifest themselves this way.

Comment: @sourav How do we check if UIButton has 3D touch enabled?

Comment: You can check in you code , weather you have added it or not .

Comment: No I haven't added any 3D touch, also there is no constraints exceptions.

Comment: If you use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25963257/how-to-get-the-3d-view-of-ui-in-xcode-6 do you see something above your buttons that could intercept the touch?

Comment: @Larme ; I checked view debugger, there is nothing above button. And to be sure I enable 'Highlight on Touch' property of UIButton. I can clearly see button is getting highlighted on touch but nothing happens

Comment: Just now I noticed when you press very gently then it works but not on normal button touches like in other devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If you have used any UIButton Category and Overrides the Touch methods
>   then try adding:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
        [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}


- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
        [super touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
}

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
        [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
}
```